# Error while renaming files using os.rename()

Tags: python, file-rename

I am using python to rename files which exist as binary files but in actual are images. So I need to rename them into .jpg format. I am using os.rename() but getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addext.py", line 8, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, filename + '.jpg')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here's my code.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('/home/gpuuser/Aditya_Nigam/lum2/'):
    # print(filename + '.jpg')
    # k = str(filename)
    # print k
    # k = filename + '.jpg'
    os.rename(filename, filename + '.jpg')

print('Done')
```

Comment: Try adding path with filename in os.rename

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, it will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) only return a list of filenames without their absolute paths, and [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) will attempt to lookup a filename from the current directory unless given an absolute path.  Basically, the code as-is will only work when executed in the same directory as the one called by `os.listdir`.

Consider doing the following:

```
import os
from os.path import join

path = '/home/gpuuser/Aditya_Nigam/lum2/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(join(path, filename), join(path, filename) + '.jpg')
```

The [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) method will safely join the path with the filenames together in a platform agnostic manner.